# With PHP or JS, can we tell at all if a file finished downloading on user's machine?

Tags: php, file-io, header, download, output

Is it possible to tell, either from PHP level or with JavaScript, that a file finished downloading on user's browser?

I have a PHP method that sets headers and then readfile(). And I need to log the name of the file and time of a download. Attempts I've made with simply logging the data AFTER readfile or fread were a failure - it would log the data but long before file is downloaded. Now I understand it's because those methods are outputting the file content into the buffer, which means, the very next line of code is triggered after file is output, not after download is finished (correct me if this claim is not correct).

So, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: from php, no. at most you can tell when the last byte has been fired out PHP's front door, e.g. `readfile('download.txt'); echo 'done!'`. when you get done, the readfile's done. but that just means PHP's done spitting out bytes - it tells you NOTHING about how many of those bytes have actually reached the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

With JS, you can know if the browser is done loading. Using the jQuery function [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) (which is triggered only after the DOM, i.e. all the elements of your page, is fully loaded) you could trigger an AJAX call back to your server to inform you the browser finished loading.

There's no way to do this from PHP because you can only know if the data is sent, not received.

```
$(document).ready({
    // Trigger an AJAX call here
});
```

Comment: Inside the page the person is loading. You have to have their browser notify you when they're done.

Comment: But in this case the 'page' is the file, isn't? File can continue to download in the browser after closing the website it was downloaded from. Also it can be paused and resumed after few hours

Comment: You might want to add a page that can load the other page then (although I'm not sure how that would affect this script).

Comment: I'm really not sure how is this supposed to work at all to be honest with $(document).ready